# iOS UIWebView on DOM Ready

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, onload

My problem is that UIWebView fires webViewDidFinishLoad before its content was rendered, therefore after I display the view I get a short delay before content of the view is displayed. Is it possible to fire an event when DOM is fully rendered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use JavaScript for this. In your HTML page add a window.onload JavaScript handler, then when it fires you can do one of two things:

1. call out to the application by loading a fake URL and intercepting this with the webview delegate. E.g.

   ```
   //in your web page, in javascript

   window.onload = function() { document.location.href = 'http://madeupdomain.com/loaded'};

   //webview delegate in cocoa

   - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
   {
       NSURL *URL = [request URL];
       NSString *host = URL.host;
       if ([host isEqualToString:@"madeupdomain.com"])
       {
           //the webview has finished loading, so show it
           webview.hidden = NO;

           return NO;
       }
       return YES;
   }
   ```
2. set a variable flag in your javascript code, then have the application poll the webview with a timer calling stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString on the webview to see if that flag has been set yet.

   ```
   //in your web page, in javascript

   window.pageHasLoaded = false;
   window.onload = function() { window.pageHasLoaded = true; };

   //in a timer in your native app code

   if ([[webview stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:@"window.pageHasLoaded"] isEqualToString:@"true"])
   {
        webview.hidden = NO;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@interface LoadNewsPageController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@end



@implementation LoadNewsPageController {

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.webView.delegate = self;

    NSLog(@"%@", self.newsObject.url);
    NSURL *websiteUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:websiteUrl];
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    if ([[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.readyState"] isEqualToString:@"complete"]) {
        // UIWebView object has fully loaded.
        NSLog(@"Dom ready");

    }
}


@end
```